# Select Multiple divs with the same ID

Tags: javascript, wordpress, firebase-realtime-database

I have looped through my posts and the result is multiple posts on a summary page. I am also using firebase realtime database to store certain info for these posts. I am querying the firebase realtime database to see what data is stored under a post id.
Unfortunately I am only getting a result for the 1st post and subsequent posts aren't getting any data.

After some research I have learned that you cannot choose multiple div's with the same ID as ID's are supposed to be unique on the HTML page.

The original script is

```
    document.getElementById().title
```

I have tried the following:

```
      document.getElementsByName().title
      document.getElementsByClass().title
```

but these syntax are not right. Any advice as to how I can shape my query to get the desired result.

Comment: use `getElementsByClassName('yourclassname')[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `document.querySelectorAll(".className")` to select all the elements on a page that fit the specified criteria. `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` both target elements using the css-like keywords.
Then you could loop through all the elements that it returns:

```
let postList = document.querySelectorAll(".post-class-name")

for (let i = 0; i < postList.length; i++)
    console.log(postList[i].title)
    // Will log the title of each post
```

However, please note that the title attribute is the text that appears after hovering on an element. Maybe add a class to each of the titles called `post-title` and replacing `.post-class-name` with `.post-title` and then instead of finding `postList[i].title` you could find `postList[i].innerText` which will return the title of each post's title

Comment: We have progress. I see the topics. I know have to query the firebase database and display the results.

Comment: I am trying to understand the second bit. How would I create a class post-title

Comment: I was thinking of adding it in the html, where it says `class=""`  inside of the quotes just add post-title

Comment: I understand now. The titles are being logged, however when I query the realtime database I am getting the following Uncaught Reference Error: i is not defined at postList[i].title

Comment: I have made i global by replacing let with var, which has now brought another problem. Uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Comment: is it still inside of the for loop? If it is, make sure you're looping through the length of the correct element

Comment: I am going to accept this answer. Everything is working properly. It was the way I typed the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind could you press the tick to accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It will be **document.getElementsByClassName().title** instead of document.getElementsByClass().title

Comment: This doesn't work. It comes up as undefined in the console log